# React Native: continue to the next screen saving the state text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native. I've got a `textInput` that takes the key of an object and saves it.

```
    submit(){
      for (let key of Object.keys(listadoPrep)) {
        if(this.state.sueldo <= listadoPrep[key][0]) {
            alert(key);
          }
      }
    }
```

As soon as it saves the key, I want to have a new screen with a different `textInput`, to save a new one. I've seen some react-navigation videos, but I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction.

As soon as I click the button, I want to have a new screen to add new text input.

[image: this is how the screen looks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question correctly, you already have code to get the key, but dont know how to save that value so that you can use it in other screen in React Native?
It is really possible and we normally use this case every time.
Then I suggest two ways to apply this.

1. React Navigation 
   You can pass the key value to navigation as props then you can use it on arriving screen as you wish.
   `Reach this doc:` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/
2. React Redux 
   You can use redux store to save the any value to use it in any screen. Redux is very useful storage to be used for React Native development.

You can choose one of these but if you get just started React Native I recommend you to get picture of React Native and master react navigation and redux.